# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running error ( in Scrape Tweets and create Dataset using Twint without Twitter API)

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to run the below method in kaggel notebook ([here](https://www.kaggle.com/sotest/notebook7bd54044af)):

[How to Scrape Tweets and create Dataset using Twint without Twitter API](https://www.kaggle.com/general/207512)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVy85.png)

but I get this error with addressing the keyword for it:

```
#Cities list of Pakistan
all_cities = ["Bagh", ...]

def scrape_by_city(keywords, since, outfile):
    unique_cities=set(all_cities) #To get unique cities of country
    cities = sorted(unique_cities) #Sort & convert datatype to list
    for city in cities:
        print(city)
        c = twint.Config()
        c.Search = keywords #search keyword
        c.Since = since
        c.Store_csv = True
        c.Output = "./" + outfile
        c.Near = city
        c.Hide_output = True
        c.Count = True
        c.Stats = True
        c.Resume = 'resume.txt'
        twint.run.Search(c)
scrape_by_city('', '2020-08-5 15:55:00', 'Pakistan_Tweets_Dataset.csv')
```

error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_38/2533700091.py in <module>
     19         twint.run.Search(c)
     20 
---> 21 scrape_by_city('', '2020-08-5 15:55:00', 'Pakistan_Tweets_Dataset.csv')

...
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py in _check_runnung(self)
    521     def _check_runnung(self):
    522         if self.is_running():
--> 523             raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    524         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    525             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Thanks.

Comment: how do you run it? If you run in Jupyter then maybe it runs previous code in other cell.

Comment: Thank @furas, I don't know why this happens, but if you like to test that code take a look at [this](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/23026) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLAthlX816c) and I guess you get the method to run the kaggle codes

Comment: i run code normally `python script.py` and I can't get this error but also I can't get any results. Kaggle post is 10 months old, code on GitHub is also few months old - and maybe meanwhile twitter could change web page code and this module may need also changes to work correctly.

Comment: I will repeate: how do you run it? Do you run it normally `python script.py` or in `Jupyter` or on `Kaggle`? Maybe this code is still running in some cell in `Jupyter`/`Kaggle` and you try to run it again in other cell. When I run `python script.py` then it runs without this error.

Comment: Ya, I have run it in the `Kaggle` site, and I get this problem.

Comment: run it in normal way - `python script.py`